# Parent dies before child in for loop

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to create 2 children and then they get and argument which tells how many children those 2 have to create like so:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bR3tTNP.png?1]

I get 2 arguments for example 2 and 3 and they have to create that many. I did it with for and it kinda works but parent dies before his second child dies

```
edvsil@os:~/4laboras$ ./testas 2 3
pid=389 ppid=387
pid=390 ppid=387
pid=386 ppid=27959
pid=391 ppid=388
edvsil@os:~/4laboras$ pid=387 ppid=1
pid=392 ppid=388
pid=388 ppid=1
pid=393 ppid=388
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
pid_t child1;
pid_t child2;
int i, a, b;
child1 = fork();
if (child1 != 0){
    child2=fork();
}
if (child1 == 0){
    for (i=1; i<=atoi(argv[1]); i++){
        if (a !=0){
            a=fork();
            if (a == 0){
            printf("pid=%d ppid=%d\n", getpid(),getppid());
            exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
else
if (child2 == 0){
    for (i=1; i<=atoi(argv[2]); i++){
        if(b !=0){
            b=fork();
            if (b == 0){
            printf("pid=%d ppid=%d\n", getpid(),getppid());
            exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("pid=%d ppid=%d\n", getpid(),getppid());
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `wait` or `waitpid` to wait in parent until all children finish execution.

Be careful not to create a fork bomb.

Comment: where i shoud put wait?  I puted it in `if (child1 != 0){
 child2=fork();
 wait(NULL);
}` but it didn't work

Comment: In parent. He should wait for the kids to die.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    pid_t child1;
    pid_t child2;
    int status;
    int i, a, b;
    child1 = fork();
    if (child1 != 0){
        child2=fork();
    }
    if (child1 != 0 & child2 != 0){
        wait(&status);
    }
    if (child1 == 0){
    for (i=1; i<=atoi(argv[1]); i++){
        if (a !=0){
            a=fork();
            if (a == 0){
                printf("pid=%d ppid=%d\n", getpid(),getppid());
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        }
    }
    else if (child2 == 0){
        printf("pid=%d ppid=%d\n", getpid(),getppid());
        for (i=1; i<=atoi(argv[2]); i++){
            if(b !=0){
                b=fork();
                if (b == 0){
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    exit(status);
    }
    printf("pid=%d ppid=%d\n", getpid(),getppid());
    return 0;
}
```